# Clicking menu item in angular js application using protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

The left menu of the application that I am currently testing is a lengthy one. And the activities in the application is so dependent on this navigation menu. So basically I tried to write a function where the input will be the menu item and inside the function that item will get clicked.

I am confused with how I can set the element variable so that I can loop it through with the menu item name for navigation.

The HTML is as given below

```
    <div class="left-sidebar-menu">
    <ul class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer" tabindex="9999">
    <li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

    <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

    <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Family Dashboard</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

    <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Calendar</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">
    <span class="menu-group-name" style="background-color: rgb(125, 16, 125);">
       HR</span>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

    <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My HR</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

    <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0" class="activeMenu"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> Benefits</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

    <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o"></i> Events</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

    <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> Bulletin Board</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

       <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Literature</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

       <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Documents</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">
    <span class="menu-group-name" style="background-color: rgb(0, 114, 188);">
       Wellness</span>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

       <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> Wellness Assessments</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

       <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-snowflake-o"></i> Wellness Programs</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

       <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-gift"></i> Wellness Challenges</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

       <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Rewards</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

       <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-television"></i> Digital Coaching</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">
    <span class="menu-group-name" style="background-color: rgb(27, 106, 12);">
       Health</span>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

    <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><img src="https://www.gogch.com/app/assets/img/gch_live_left_icon.png" class="benefit-menuicon"> Live</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

       <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> Care Programs </div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

       <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i> Vitals</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

       <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Health Profile</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

    <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-medkit"></i> Medications</div>

    </li><li class="mainMenu nav navbar-nav side-nav scrollBoxContainer">

    <div routerlinkactive="activeMenu" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-eyedropper"></i>  Immunizations</div>

    </li>
    </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: could you provide us exactly what items are you trying to click, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to click on the menu items. Say Click on "Literature" by passing the menu name to a function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that was your meaning, but you can make a function that gets a list of elements and filtering the wanted element:

```
const menuItems = element.all(by.css('div[routerlinkactive="activeMenu"]');

const itemClick = (itemsList, itemString) => {
    itemsList.filter((item) => item.getText() === itemString).first().click();
};

itemClick(menuItems, "Home");
```

Comment: Got an error. _ Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, div[routerlinkactive="activeMenu"])_